# Как преобразовать список строк в словари?

Tags: python, json, парсер, list, словари

Мне прилетает список, в нем элементы в виде строки.
Нужно эти элементы преобразовать в словари.

Вот список:

```
['"id_lady":"1535570", "lady":"Svitlana, 47", "bonuses":"0.66"', '"id_lady":"15407058", "lady":"Anzhela, 35", "bonuses":"9.08"', '"id_lady":"15750452", "lady":"Victoriya, 49", "bonuses":"29.72"', '"id_lady":"15753026", "lady":"Anna, 28", "bonuses":"0.77"', '"id_lady":"17854550", "lady":"Inna, 35", "bonuses":"0.22"', '"id_lady":"22532812", "lady":"Anna, 30", "bonuses":"1.10"', '"id_lady":"24829304", "lady":"Natalia, 62", "bonuses":"4.59"', '"id_lady":"42940723", "lady":"Viktoriya, 30", "bonuses":"0.11"', '"id_lady":"49072712", "lady":"Kateryna, 29", "bonuses":"1.10"', '"id_lady":"49307758", "lady":"Inna, 49", "bonuses":"1.54"','"id_lady":"54397914", "lady":"Inna, 31", "bonuses":"0.66"', '"id_lady":"59258962", "lady":"Irina, 48", "bonuses":"0.11"', '"id_lady":"60286482", "lady":"Tatiana, 42", "bonuses":"2.75"', '"id_lady":"63361546", "lady":"Yelyzaveta, 20", "bonuses":"0.66"', '"id_lady":"63445241", "lady":"Albina, 26", "bonuses":"0.44"', '"id_lady":"63799796", "lady":"Yana, 31", "bonuses":"0.11"', '"id_lady":"63812232", "lady":"Anna, 41", "bonuses":"16.86"', '"id_lady":"63988599", "lady":"Oksana, 31", "bonuses":"0.11"', '"id_lady":"64333441", "lady":"Tatyana, 24", "bonuses":"0.33"', '"id_lady":"64501583", "lady":"Olha, 32", "bonuses":"0.33"', '"id_lady":"64928163", "lady":"Alina, 36", "bonuses":"0.44"']
```

Если пройтись условием и выводить каждый элемент по очередности (список[0] и т.д.), то получается строка в таком виде:

```
"id_lady":"1535570", "lady":"Svitlana, 47", "bonuses":"0.66"
```

Вот такие строки нужно сделать набором словарей, типа каждая строка это отдельный словарь

UPD Добавил код и пояснения, что делал:

```
from ast import literal_eval


test = ['"id_lady":"1535570", "lady":"Svitlana, 47", "bonuses":"0.66"', '"id_lady":"15407058", "lady":"Anzhela, 35", "bonuses":"9.08"', '"id_lady":"15750452", "lady":"Victoriya, 49", "bonuses":"29.72"', '"id_lady":"15753026", "lady":"Anna, 28", "bonuses":"0.77"', '"id_lady":"17854550", "lady":"Inna, 35", "bonuses":"0.22"', '"id_lady":"22532812", "lady":"Anna, 30", "bonuses":"1.10"', '"id_lady":"24829304", "lady":"Natalia, 62", "bonuses":"4.59"', '"id_lady":"42940723", "lady":"Viktoriya, 30", "bonuses":"0.11"', '"id_lady":"49072712", "lady":"Kateryna, 29", "bonuses":"1.10"', '"id_lady":"49307758", "lady":"Inna, 49", "bonuses":"1.54"','"id_lady":"54397914", "lady":"Inna, 31", "bonuses":"0.66"', '"id_lady":"59258962", "lady":"Irina, 48", "bonuses":"0.11"', '"id_lady":"60286482", "lady":"Tatiana, 42", "bonuses":"2.75"', '"id_lady":"63361546", "lady":"Yelyzaveta, 20", "bonuses":"0.66"', '"id_lady":"63445241", "lady":"Albina, 26", "bonuses":"0.44"', '"id_lady":"63799796", "lady":"Yana, 31", "bonuses":"0.11"', '"id_lady":"63812232", "lady":"Anna, 41", "bonuses":"16.86"', '"id_lady":"63988599", "lady":"Oksana, 31", "bonuses":"0.11"', '"id_lady":"64333441", "lady":"Tatyana, 24", "bonuses":"0.33"', '"id_lady":"64501583", "lady":"Olha, 32", "bonuses":"0.33"', '"id_lady":"64928163", "lady":"Alina, 36", "bonuses":"0.44"']

print(type(test))
# Вывод - <class 'list'>

# вытягиваю первый элемент списка
d = test[0]

print(d)
# Вывод - "id_lady":"1535570", "lady":"Svitlana, 47", "bonuses":"0.66"

print(type(d))
# вывод - <class 'str'>

# Пробовал таким методом
de = literal_eval(d)
print(de)
# Вывод - "id_lady":"1535570", "lady":"Svitlana, 47", "bonuses":"0.66"
#                  ^
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Очень хорошо, что нужно. Ваш код где?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Давайте начнем с того, что вот это : "id_lady":"1535570", "lady":"Svitlana, 47", "bonuses":"0.66"  -  никак не строка. Это то-ли недоделаный список, то-ли разобранная по фрагментом строка, то-ли три строки перечисленные через запятую (чего в Python быть не должно).  Для начала четко укажите, какому типу данных Python относится этот объект? Как он виден интерпретатору или хотя-бы как вы его получили.  Дальше посмотрим.

Comment: @passant похоже на список с одним элементом-строкой: `['"id_lady": ... "bonuses":"0.44"']` в начале и в конце - еще одна одинарная кавычка...

Comment: @Jack_oS я тоже так подумал, но там  могут быть сюрпризы. Посмотрите, в исходном сообщении каждая такая триада оформлена в отдельные одиночные кавычки, т.е. вообще-то может быть рассмотрена как отдельная строка. А может быть уже разобрана на компоненты, и каждый из  них -  теперь отдельная строка.  В общем надо уточнение. Хочется увидеть код автора получения хотя-бы этого результата..

Comment: @passant так и есть: если присвоить это в `my_list` то `len(my_list)` даст 21, а `my_list[0]` - `'"id_lady":"1535570", "lady":"Svitlana, 47", "bonuses":"0.66"'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если элементы входного списка гарантированно в формате питона, то:

```
res = [eval("{"+el+"}") for el in input_list]
```

Comment: Получилось, большое спасибо. Всем кто тоже помогал спасибки)) Всем здоровья

Answer (score 4):

```
str_list = ['"id_lady":"1535570", "lady":"Svitlana, 47", "bonuses":"0.66"', '"id_lady":"15407058", "lady":"Anzhela, 35", "bonuses":"9.08"', '"id_lady":"15750452", "lady":"Victoriya, 49", "bonuses":"29.72"', '"id_lady":"15753026", "lady":"Anna, 28", "bonuses":"0.77"', '"id_lady":"17854550", "lady":"Inna, 35", "bonuses":"0.22"', '"id_lady":"22532812", "lady":"Anna, 30", "bonuses":"1.10"', '"id_lady":"24829304", "lady":"Natalia, 62", "bonuses":"4.59"', '"id_lady":"42940723", "lady":"Viktoriya, 30", "bonuses":"0.11"', '"id_lady":"49072712", "lady":"Kateryna, 29", "bonuses":"1.10"', '"id_lady":"49307758", "lady":"Inna, 49", "bonuses":"1.54"','"id_lady":"54397914", "lady":"Inna, 31", "bonuses":"0.66"', '"id_lady":"59258962", "lady":"Irina, 48", "bonuses":"0.11"', '"id_lady":"60286482", "lady":"Tatiana, 42", "bonuses":"2.75"', '"id_lady":"63361546", "lady":"Yelyzaveta, 20", "bonuses":"0.66"', '"id_lady":"63445241", "lady":"Albina, 26", "bonuses":"0.44"', '"id_lady":"63799796", "lady":"Yana, 31", "bonuses":"0.11"', '"id_lady":"63812232", "lady":"Anna, 41", "bonuses":"16.86"', '"id_lady":"63988599", "lady":"Oksana, 31", "bonuses":"0.11"', '"id_lady":"64333441", "lady":"Tatyana, 24", "bonuses":"0.33"', '"id_lady":"64501583", "lady":"Olha, 32", "bonuses":"0.33"', '"id_lady":"64928163", "lady":"Alina, 36", "bonuses":"0.44"']
```

преобразуйте в словари с `json.loads()`, добавляя фигурные кавычки в начала и в конце каждой строки ('{' и  '}'), например:

```
import json

dict_list = [json.loads('{'+x+'}') for x in str_list]
```

или через `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
import ast

dict_list = [ast.literal_eval('{'+x+'}') for x in str_list]
```

тогда в `dict_list` будет

```
>>> dict_list
[
    {'id_lady': '1535570', 'lady': 'Svitlana, 47', 'bonuses': '0.66'},
    {'id_lady': '15407058', 'lady': 'Anzhela, 35', 'bonuses': '9.08'}, 
    {'id_lady': '15750452', 'lady': 'Victoriya, 49', 'bonuses': '29.72'}, 

    ...

    {'id_lady': '64333441', 'lady': 'Tatyana, 24', 'bonuses': '0.33'}, 
    {'id_lady': '64501583', 'lady': 'Olha, 32', 'bonuses': '0.33'}, 
    {'id_lady': '64928163', 'lady': 'Alina, 36', 'bonuses': '0.44'}
]
```

Comment: Добавил полный код и пояснения)

Comment: @Alexandr да, все правильно делали, только про фигурные скобки для словаря забыли

Comment: Извините, первый раз задаю тут ответ и не полностью разобрался))